# Extract the names of the named entities using MID in Freebase

Tags: freebase

How can I obtain the names from the mids in Freebase? In the following table_row in music/album table we have the following album names(?) provided in mid.

```
music|artist|name   id  origin  active_start    active_end  genre   label           home_page   acquire_webpage album   contribution    track   track_contributions concert_tours   supporting_artists|Jimmy Johnson    /m/01wz6jx              Rock music,Jazz fusion,Jazz,Folk rock                   /m/01wz6kq,/m/01wz6kx,/m/01wz6l8,/m/01wz6kj,/m/01wz6kb,/m/01wz6l2,/m/01wz6lg        /m/0fjw1yt,/m/0dt2p4t,/m/0fbpmv2,/m/0ffbzh3,/m/0f7y3jb,/m/0fgb1g1,/m/0dy5n14,/m/0fgn9xv,/m/0dzbwfr,/m/0f6hyd3,/m/0fj70dm,/m/0ff_qzm,/m/0f9_cm4,/m/0f7l2cj,/m/0fkhd4j,/m/0flf7j8,/m/0flr1z_,/m/0fl3c6q,/m/0ffp8g9,/m/0f64lc8,/m/0fgzlz2,/m/0f885wn,/m/0fktd7t,/m/0d_j0p6,/m/0dv915z,/m/0fm0 _t2
```

If I query Freebase like this: `[{
  "mid": "/m/01wz6kq",
  "name": null
}]​`

then I obtain a "null" for name. How can I obtain the names? Are these mids at all pointing to named entities? If I use the freebase website like this: `http://www.freebase.com/view/m/01wz6kq` then I obtain `Contributor: Jimmy Johnson
Album: All Night Wrong` meaning that the album name exists.
However, if I use: `http://api.freebase.com/api/experimental/topic/standard?id=/m/01wz6kq` i.e. the TOPIC API, then the information is "extractable" from the text field. Is this the way to do it? or is there any other easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better view of this data if you're doing programming is the explore/inspect view:

http://www.freebase.com/inspect/m/01wz6kq

As a matter of fact, it even gives you a little shortcut for building a query.  If you click on the arrow to the left of the `/music/recording_contribution/album` property, you'll get a pre-built query which you can modify to fetch the name instead of the ID:

```
{
  "id": "/m/01wz6kq",
  "/music/recording_contribution/album": {
    "name": null
  }
}​
```

If you click on the Link button in the [Query Editor](https://dev.freebase.com/query?lang=/lang/en&q=%7B%22id%22%3a%22/m/01wz6kq%22,%22/music/recording_contribution/contributor%22%3a%7B%22name%22%3anull%7D%7D) you'll get an [MQLRead link](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread/?lang=/lang/en&query=%7B%20%22id%22%3a%20%22/m/01wz6kq%22,%20%22/music/recording_contribution/contributor%22%3a%20%7B%20%22name%22%3a%20null%20%7D%20%7D) that gives you back JSON you can parse to get the name.

Of course if you were doing this in the program, you'd construct the URL on the fly from a template with the ID of interest inserted.

NOTE: you do not want to be doing anything that references api.freebase.com because that's going away soon.  You should be using the googleapis.com endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Tom! This is awesome. You are also right: I am going to use this is in my code. But this technique of using "inspect" involves manual intervention. I have to modify the query to put the "name" field. Also, obtaining the query itself will be non-trivial? Is there any simpler way to use the API to get the name?

Comment: Sorry, implicit in my reply was that you'd use the (parameterized) query with the MQL Read API.  Since you mentioned the topic API, I thought perhaps you were already aware of it.  I've updated my answer to make it clearer (and also warn about using the deprecated API endpoint).

Comment: Thanks Tom! I had one more question but this is regarding the googleapis.com. I use my API Key for other queries but if I use the topic utility of googleapis and use it for a large number of queries how can I put the key in( or the key is not required as of now?)? This way does not work: [code]https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/01wz6kq&key=xyzblahblah[/code]

Answer (score 0):

This entity has no `/type/object/name` property

BTW
If you want to extract entity names, there are some properties:

```
/type/object/name
/common/topic/alias
```

and wikipedia keys, which need to be processed in some way (replace "_" with space, "&" with "&", "$1234" with some unicode symbol)